# MOSS 2007 Unique Site Permissions

Tags: permissions

I have two sharepoint web applications. In first one when I create a subsite I get these options to set user permissions for new sub site in the site creation form i.e.

[image]

In the second application I don't get this option. I have Office publishing feature enabled on both. I tried enabling/disabling Office enterprise features and standard features but nothing is working. Can someone give an idea of how to enable this on the second web application.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: so in 2nd web application you don't get  user permissions option at all ? or just not "Use unique permissions" and did you created both web applications with same settings ?

Comment: in the second application I don't get any of this option in screenshot. The applications were created by someone else and I don't know what settings were used.

Comment: could be something related to managed path (that happens with site collections), not sure if it could happen to web applications though :), you can try creating new web applications and get yourself familiarize with settings and see if you can regenerate this situation unless someone else help you here :)

Comment: Just an idea is anonymous access enabled on te second web app?

Comment: Are you a site collection administrator on the site collection?

Answer (score 1):

I haven't got any issues like this, but worth to check, whether you are the Site Collection Administrator or just the Site Administrator?
Even both are same admin, but both have different sets of view in Site Settings.

Secondly, if you really are a Site Collection Admin and still getting this kind of error, you can still create subsite without that settings. But once the site is created, you can go to the new site, and use unique permission on that subsite settings (Stop Inherit Permission) from Site Settings.